# Multithreading in JavaFX hangs the UI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx

I have a simple JavaFX 2 app, with 2 buttons, saying Start and Stop. When the start button is clicked, I want to create a background thread which will do some processing and update the UI (e.g a progress bar) as it goes along. If the stop button is clicked, I want the thread to terminate.

I've tried to do this using the `javafx.concurrent.Task` class which I gathered from the documentation would work fine for this. But whenever I click Start, the UI freezes/hangs rather than staying normal.

Her's the code from the main `Myprogram extends Application` class for showing the buttons:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{               
    final Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Begin");

    //This is the thread, extending javafx.concurrent.Task :
    final MyProcessor handler = new MyProcessor();
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {                
           handler.run(); 
        }
    });

    Button stop = new Button();
    stop.setText("Stop");
    stop.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
             public void handle(ActionEvent event)
             {
                handler.cancel();
             }
        }

    );
    // Code for adding the UI controls to the stage here.
}
```

Here's the code of `MyProcessor` class:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
public class MyProcessor extends Task
{   
    @Override
    protected Integer call()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (String symbol : feed.getSymbols() )
        {
            if ( isCancelled() )
            {
                Logger.log("Stopping!");
                return i;
            }
            i++;
            Logger.log("Doing # " + i);
            //Processing code here which takes 2-3 seconds per iteration to execute
            Logger.log("# " + i + ", DONE! ");            
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Pretty simple, but the UI hangs whenever I click the Start button, though the console messages continue to get displayed (`Logger.log` simply does `System.out.println` )

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Task` implements `Runnable`, so when you call `handler.run();` you actually run the `call` method in the UI Thread. That will hang the UI.

You should start the task in a background thread, either via an executor or simply by calling `new Thread(handler).start();`.

This is explained (maybe not very clearly) in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or in the [JavaFX concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

Comment: I have one more question. I want to update a label in the main UI with the progress of the task thread. For this I would use this code in the task: `mainProg.updateStatus(i);`, and in main program: `public void updateStatus(int i) { this.label.setText(i) ); }`. Would this work, or should I use `platform.runLater()` from `MainProg.updateStatus()` for updating the UI?

Comment: Yes you would need to run it in the UI Thread with runLater - Alternatively, you can use the updateProgress method (see example 3 in the tutorial) which will run in the UI thread.

Comment: For those who reach this topic searching an answer how to bind backend tasks and UI so that backend updates UI, I recommend this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/enterprisefx-1651840.html . It somehow explains topic littlebit better than "JavaFX concurrency tutorial", which comes up with every Google search.

Comment: @TaaviIlves how is your link relevant? "Learn to use LightView to convert REST services into a bindable set of properties".

Comment: Only so that it explains communication with backend and frontend with working example more verbose. For specific question & answer it's not that relevant indeed. I wasn't misleading on purpose, but lots of googling always brought me to "JavaFX concurrency tutorial" that didn't help me much firsthand.